# Storing a variable inside mysql text field

Tags: php, html, mysql

What technique should I use to enter a `$variable` inside a block of text to store in mysql. 
For example:

> Dear {name}, here is some stored text from the database. 
>   Thanks {company_name}

After retrieving that, I'm guessing I would use something like `preg_replace` to then convert the variable to a value like this

> Dear Mr Smith, here is some stored text from the database. 
>   Thanks Company Ltd

I know I could just use `preg_replace` but how would I avoid it replacing words with the same letters as the variable?

Answer (score 5):

Why not use `str_replace('{name}',$name,$text);`

Comment: I was assuming it would be as simple as that for the echo. Is {variable} in the text the normal way? or [variable] etc..

Comment: It's up to you.  It just needs to be something that is not going to naturally be in your text.  You could even use something like {[variable]}, just so long as it is unlikely to be mistakenly matched.  I used a templating program that did a regex on [] but it would mistakenly parse jaascript arrays.  So I changed it to {[ ]} and never had problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand, but having variables inside a block of text is rather simple;

```
$variable = 'Mr John';
echo 'Hello '.$variable.' this is a variable inside a block of text.';
```

Comment: The block of text is to be stored in a database first (with an unknown name),  then retrieve and edit as you described.

Comment: Ait, then I'd probably go with @KevinP's answer. That is of course, that you save a block of text, retrieve it from the database and then just replace the `{name}` with the new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Before storing your text, make sure the name of your variables are wrapped between special characters that you would never use in a text, like <>, and then you can use `preg_replace` safely.